# creating homemade scrollbars in web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, mouse, scrollbars

For years I have had a problem using javascript and jquery to control things like homemade scrollbars.  I use mousedown to set a "dragging" variable to true, save the initial mouse position, and then use mousemove to track the mouse and set the div position.  I condition everything on "dragging" so that once the user lets go of the mouse, or moves far enough away, then "dragging" is cleared and everything stops tracking.

The problem is, I have trouble finding out for sure when they let go of the mouse.  I use mouseup and mouseout of course, but this has two problems.  One is that I want the user to be able to wander outside the div being scrolled a small amount, like 10 pixels, without losing the tracking.  The other problem is that sometimes I miss an event and "dragging" stays set and the mouse gets "stuck to the div" and they have problems letting go.

I need a solution.  It can either be some plugin or a coding technique.  I have used a number of different techniques over the years but I've never gotten a simple perfect solution.

Comment: Please, don't do this unless you have a very specific reason for doing so.

Comment: Don't do what?  I have to make a custom scrollbar, my client refuses to show the standard ugly ones.  Google uses custom bars all over their sites.

Comment: Just because Google does it doesn't mean that it helps usability.  If your client is worried about scrollbars... then good luck.  :-)  Do what you have to do.

Comment: +1 "custom" scrollbars are almost always horrible from a usability standpoint: scrollwheel support, hit area, etc. I believe google is actually using `-webkit-*` properties for gmail rather than rolling their own.

Comment: Are there equivalents for -webkit-* in all browsers?  Gmail works in all browsers.  BTW, my scrollbars have always supported scrollwheels, hit areas, etc.  I see custom scrollbars all over the web.  Surely someone has an answer for my problem.

Comment: Is jquery allowed? if so you might consider checking this out http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Comment: I find it interesting that I got multiple people telling me I shouldn't be doing what I need to do and zero people helping. No one would even answer the straighforward question "Are there equivalents for -webkit-* in all browsers?". This is not a good first stackoverflow experience.